# Target Nav Menu with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to target an href button and a menu to fade in as the page loads. I'm having trouble trying to figure out the exact code since it is placed inside so many different tags and I'm fairly new to JS and JQuery. I have included a fiddle with all the code.

So far I have managed this code:

HTML:

```
<div id="ImageMain">

<ul id="nav">
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Men</a></li>
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Women</a></li>
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="#" id="homeb">Shop Now</a>

</div>

<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#navm").fadeIn(500);
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#homeb").fadeIn(500);
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#ImageMain {
background-image: url(http://juliapavel.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/DSC1139-1.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 1400px;
text-align: center;
color: black;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-top: 0px;
position: relative;
}

#ImageMain h1 {
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 450px;
}

#homeinfo {
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#brand {
float: left;
padding: 100px;
}

#Pronto {
width: 150px;
}

#ImageMain #brand a {
font-size: 20px;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

#nav #navm a {
transition-duration: 1s;
}

#brand a:hover {
opacity: .3;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

#navm a:hover {
opacity: .3;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

#navm {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
display: none;
}

#homeb {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
border-radius: 5px;
border: solid 1px black;
padding: 12px;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

#wrapper a {
text-decoration: none;
border: solid 1px #141414;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px;
color: #141414;
}

#homeb:hover {
opacity: .3;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

#wrapper a:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

h3 {
color: white;
}

#nav {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
padding-top: 5px;
text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 7px;
}

#nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tux41Lvp/

Comment: IDs must only be used ONCE in a document - you are using `#navm` three times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a parent div to the button anchor:

```
<div id="link">
    <a href="#" id="homeb">Shop Now</a>
</div>
```

You need to hide the target elements( you have to target parents ):

```
#nav{ display:none;}
#link{ display:none;}
```

Look at js on the working snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#nav").fadeIn(500);
            $("#link").fadeIn(1000);
        });
```

```css
#ImageMain {
 background-image: url(http://juliapavel.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/DSC1139-1.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 1400px;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 padding-top: 0px;
 position: relative;
}

#ImageMain h1 {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 450px;
}

#homeinfo {
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#brand {
 float: left;
 padding: 100px;
}

#Pronto {
 width: 150px;
}

#ImageMain #brand a {
 font-size: 20px;
 transition-duration: 1s;
}

#nav #navm a {
 transition-duration: 1s;
}

#brand a:hover {
 opacity: .3;
 transition-duration: 1s;
}

#navm a:hover {
 opacity: .3;
 transition-duration: 1s;
}

#navm {
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 display: none;
}

#homeb {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: solid 1px black;
 padding: 12px;
 transition-duration: 1s;
}

#wrapper a {
 text-decoration: none;
 border: solid 1px #141414;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #141414;
}

#homeb:hover {
 opacity: .3;
 transition-duration: 1s;
}

#wrapper a:hover {
 opacity: 0.7;
 transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

h3 {
 color: white;
}

#nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
 padding: 7px;
}

#nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 font-size: 15px;
}

#nav{ display:none;}
#link{ display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ImageMain">
 
 <ul id="nav">
  <li id="navm"><a href="#">Men</a></li>
  <li id="navm"><a href="#">Women</a></li>
  <li id="navm"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
 
  <div id="link">
    <a href="#" id="homeb">Shop Now</a>
  </div>
 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to hide the items before showing them and you can't have two separate items with the same ID's, so I changed the selector.

```js
$("#nav a, #homeb").hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav a").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#homeb").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
#ImageMain {
background-image: url(http://juliapavel.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/DSC1139-1.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 1400px;
text-align: center;
color: black;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-top: 0px;
position: relative;
}

#ImageMain h1 {
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 450px;
}

#homeinfo {
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#brand {
float: left;
padding: 100px;
}

#Pronto {
width: 150px;
}

#ImageMain #brand a {
font-size: 20px;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

#nav #navm a {
transition-duration: 1s;
}

#brand a:hover {
opacity: .3;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

#navm a:hover {
opacity: .3;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

#navm {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
display: none;
}

#homeb {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
border-radius: 5px;
border: solid 1px black;
padding: 12px;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

#wrapper a {
text-decoration: none;
border: solid 1px #141414;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px;
color: #141414;
}

#homeb:hover {
opacity: .3;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

#wrapper a:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

h3 {
color: white;
}

#nav {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
padding-top: 5px;
text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 7px;
}

#nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ImageMain">

<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="#" id="homeb">Shop Now</a>

</div>
```